# Next js access AppContext in _document

Tags: javascript, next.js, content-security-policy

I'm using next js and my main problem is that I have some `Content-Security-Policy` issues because next js uses inline style.

So you will get `Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive` error if you don't add `'unsafe-inline'` to your `style-src`.

Allowing `unsafe-inline` is an absolute no.

Related issues for this problem is:

1. [issue 256](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/256)
2. [issue 18557](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/18557)

Since I'm using server side rendering, [the proposed solution](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/18451#discussioncomment-664707) is to attach a CSP to the response header and add a nonce to the document. ie:

```
export default class extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    const nonce = generateNonce() // however you do this is up to you
    const csp = getCSP(nonce) // we have a function that returns a string incorporating the nonce
    const res = ctx?.res
    if (res != null) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', csp)
    }
    return {
      ...initialProps,
      nonce,
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { nonce } = this.props

    return (
      <Html lang="en" dir="ltr">
        <Head nonce={nonce}>
```

The problem with this solution is, I already have `getInitialProps` in my `_app` file, and in that case the `getInitialProps` in the `_document` level won't be called.

I can generate the CSP and nonce in the `_app` `getInitialProps` but I won't be able to access the nonce in the `_document`

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext: AppContext) => {
  try {
    //... some code

    const [csp, nonce] = generateCsp();

    const res = appContext?.ctx.res;
    if (res != null) {
      console.log("I'm in");
      res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', csp);
    }
    // I try to attached the nonce in the request so I could access from _document 
    (appContext.ctx.req as any).nonce = nonce;
    
    return {
      ...initProperties,
      nonce,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      error,
    };
  }
};
```

So now I can't really remove the `getInitialProps` from the `_app` because the whole app is built based on that, so my question is, is there a way to share properties between `_app` and `_document`.

Or is there another way/solution for this CSP issues.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to pass anything from `_app` up to `_document` because `_document` runs first, but you can run `getInitialProps` in both `_app` and `_document` and they can be completely separate, so you shouldn't have to rewrite your `_app` at all. You can do your nonce/csp work in `_document` which will run before `_app`, and then leave all the rest of your code in `_app` alone.

`getInitialProps` is a component-level function which means it will run on each component you use it on, including `_document` *and* `_app` if you use it in both places. But, it only runs on the server which means your nonce won't update on client-side routing changes or live reloading in dev mode.

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    const [csp, nonce] = generateCsp()
    ctx?.res?.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', csp)
    return { ...initialProps, nonce }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head nonce={this.props.nonce} />
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Note that the `_document` `Head` component is not the same as the one from [next/head](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head). Looking at the next/head code, I didn't see where it accepts a `nonce` prop, so this needs to be done in the `_document`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying this solution in the server because locally it doesn't work.

I'm getting Type error: Property 'nonce' does not exist on type 'Readonly<RenderPageResult & { styles?: ReactFragment | ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>>[] | undefined; } & { ...; }> & Readonly<...>'.

how can you add a property to a library interface? Coming form C++ background